# String to Date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

There is the following string - "2013-10-23 11:56:29" and timezone name "Europe/Moscow". I hoped to parse it into Date using Date.parse() or new Date(string), but it doesn't work. How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

see the ISO formats: `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`

[developer.mozilla.org -  JavaScript Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

[Converting string to date in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js)

Answer (score 0):

Use moment.js (http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) and moment timezone (http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) for the timezone.

Comment: How to get Timezone offset by timezone string? For example by "europe/moscow"?